# CoreWcf Service hangs up after some time

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core, f#

I used to have some NET Framework WCF service. It worked like a clockwork. Once NET5 and [CoreWCF](https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF) were released, I migrated the service to, well, NET5 and CoreWCF.

Now it hangs up after some time. If the load is light, then it might work for a day or so (and then randomly die), but if load becomes heavier, then it may die just in an hour or so. When it dies, then I can see that it starts consuming a lot of processing power.

The clients work fine and even if I restart the service, then they will pick up the connection (after complaining for a while that the service is unavailable).

The service runs as a singleton.

Logging and then monitoring when did the logging die seems to be the only way to figure out what's going on. Unfortunately, such logging produces an outrageous amount of data and it seems producing some data even after the "core" of the service no longer operates properly.

Switching to gRPC is possible. However, this will require rewriting all clients.

Debugging is a no go because the service dies, let's say, somewhere after between one hour and one day and when it handles multiple connections and timer events.

I wonder if anyone has any ideas. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The alternative to WCF in core is gRPC: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/cloud-native/grpc

Comment: Suggestion: Run the service in a debugger and then see where it dies and/or starts consuming CPU cycles.

Comment: If you can't use a debugger, then I think logging/monitoring is your best bet. Perhaps you can reduce the amount of data logged to focus only the "core" of the service.

Comment: @brianberns, I followed your advice and it turned out that there was stupid bug on my side: instead of a singleton I was creating a lower lever underlying service at **every** WCF call. And since this low level service was spawning a `Timer` handler, then the longer the service run, the more subscriptions to `Timer` evens I had, until the system died. If you could, please, submit your comment as an answer, then I'd be glad to mark it as so. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it worked out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion: Run the service in a debugger and then see where it dies and/or starts consuming CPU cycles.

If you can't use a debugger, then I think logging/monitoring is your best bet. Perhaps you can reduce the amount of data logged to focus only the "core" of the service.